How to access MetaMask from React (Vite) Browser Extension
I need to authenticate my web extension with MetaMask. The extension is made using React and Vite, and I don't have access to window.ethereum so I'm stuck. I looked into metamask-extension-provider but I couldn't make it work. When I try to access MetaMask using Provider from the mentioned package, I get an error process is not defined.
